# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{n^n}$ rational?

Tags: real-analysis

> Is $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{n^n}$ rational?

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1185875/9464) has been posted in MSE for two years without an answer. [A094082](http://oeis.org/A094082) seems to suggest that it is not rational. Is it still an open problem? Are there any known results about it?

Comment: If your search $1.8798538621752585$ at ISC, you get only this sum and its variants.  In particular, no rational value was found. But also no value in terms of other known quantities was found.  ( http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au )

Comment: Can we not do something after which the proof of irrationality of $e$ can be imitated ?

Comment: @adityaguharoy I attempted to do just that, folloowing the proof that $e$ is irrational. I got stuck, and that is what prompted me to pose this question on MSE.